# Custom template page in Wordpress' new Gutenberg

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I would like to create a custom front page in the new Wordpress Gutenberg editor.

In older version of Wordpress I could attach a page to a custom template.

I can't see that option in Gutenberg.

Regards

Frank

Answer (score 1):

The Gutenberg Handbook on wordpress.org says about that:

> Planned additions:
>
> - Saved and assigned to pages as “page templates”.
> - Defined in a template.php file or pulled from a custom post type (wp_templates) that is site specific.
> - As the equivalent of the theme hierarchy.

(https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/block-api/block-templates/)

So apparently that isn't yet available, but is planned.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new page with wordpress gunteberg editor.

Set it as the front page (on the WordPress settings) and now you can style the whole front page.

You will probably need to install some block plugins to accomplish your needs (sliders, testimonials, carousels, responsive layouts...).

Have a look at [getblocklab.com](https://getblocklab.com) or the ACF block system (in Release Candidate right now available only for premium users) if you want to style your home similar as you would with a php template + css.